# Api integration with Reactjs and Superagent

Tags: reactjs, superagent

everyone. I'm having an issue with getting my results to render for a search using the yummly api. Here's my block of code. ..

```
import React from 'react';
import Request from 'superagent';
import _ from 'lodash';


export class Yum extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {};
}

componentWillMount(){

    var url = "http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=5129dd16&_app_key=9772f1db10ba433223ad4e765dc2b537&=q"
    Request.get(url).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.body);
        this.setState({
            recipes: response.body.matches,
            total: response.body.totalResults           
        });
    });
}

updateSearch(){
    this.search(this.refs.query.value);
}

render(){
    var recipes = _.map(this.state.recipes, (recipes) => {
        return<li>hello</li>;
    });

    return(

        <div>
            <input ref="query" onChange = { (e) => {this.updateSearch();} } type="text" />
            <ul>{}</ul>

        </div>
    )
}

search(query = "onion") {
    var url = `http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=5129dd16&_app_key=9772f1db10ba433223ad4e765dc2b537&=q=${query}`
    Request.get(url).then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            recipes: response.body.Search,
            total: response.body.totalResults
        });
    });
}
}

export default Yum;
```

I think I'm getting close to the answer. I believe it's an issue of scope. All that's showing up is the search bar, and the results are not rendering. As you can see, the console.logs are bringing up results. And I'm getting a warning saying 'Line 30: 'recipes' is assigned a value but never used.'

Comment: you need to put the `recipes` variable in the `{}` inside the `ul` tag in render

Comment: Did that. Doesn't seem to be rendering results.